# How do I install Ubuntu on my laptop with corrupted windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, usb-installation, phone

I have a two year old Asus FX570ud and recent the Windows 11 on it corrupted and now I can only boot it in safe mode. (Error code 0xc000001

I want to switch to Ubuntu and I only have my phone (which I am not willing to root) and a few 32gb flashdisks.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu in my laptop with the things I have?

Comment: See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop, and determine the answer for yourself.

Comment: @user535733 I cannot access the internet on my laptop, it's on safe mode

Comment: If you are installing a new operating system as a replacement, it's not relevant what's already on the device. You can follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). You will need a USB flash drive. 32GB is more than sufficient. You will also need access to another computer that can create the installation USB.

Comment: As previously commented, get a normal computer to make the installation media (preferred). As a last resource, if you have access only to your own phone, you may try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixapplications.iso2usb&gl=US (this comes with absolutely NO guarantees, even if "successful" the resulting media might not boot). BTW, how you burn an ISO to USB, even it's an Ubuntu ISO, it's NOT an Ubuntu question.

Comment: Ask someone to download the installation ISO and burn the installation flash drive for you.